# App crash report in Google pre-launch report FATAL EXCEPTION: UserFacing7

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I am pretty new with releasing Android apps and did get the following error for the "Google Pixel 3" device in the pre-launch report: FATAL EXCEPTION: UserFacing7.

> Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.c: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

I have tried to analyse and recreate this problem but no success. It seems like it is a java related problem and from a Unity context I have no idea how to address and fix this and really need help.

Interesting is that I have the same application, in another language, released at the same time without any errors.

Here is the stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: UserFacing7
Process: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search, PID: 9979
com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.f: EXCLUSIVE background task FETCH_OPT_IN_STATUSES crashed.
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.g.onFailure(SourceFile:25)
at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.j.onFailure(SourceFile:3)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bb.run(SourceFile:10)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bw.blu(SourceFile:3)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.bv.run(SourceFile:4)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.ba.run(SourceFile:4)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.ba.run(SourceFile:4)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.c: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.o.b.a.b(SourceFile:7)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.o.b.b.call(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.a(SourceFile:4)
at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.e.bpj(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cp.etI(SourceFile:12)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bm.run(SourceFile:19)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.co.run(SourceFile:23)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
at com.google.android.a.a.a(SourceFile:11)
at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.p.GE(SourceFile:23)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.adapter.VoiceInteractionServiceAlwaysOnHotwordAdapter.byR(SourceFile:22)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.adapter.VoiceInteractionServiceAlwaysOnHotwordAdapter.byK(SourceFile:59)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.p.bT(SourceFile:5)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.adapter.VoiceInteractionServiceAlwaysOnHotwordAdapter.c(SourceFile:117)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.adapter.VoiceInteractionServiceAlwaysOnHotwordAdapter.a(SourceFile:15)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.o.s(SourceFile:24)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.o.a(SourceFile:79)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.o.perform(SourceFile:29)
at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.o.b.a.b(SourceFile:5)
... 13 more
```

Comment: I got same error,  did you find out solution? Or is this bug MUST be depend on Google?

Comment: No solution yet